# Source configuration filr in terminal though perl script

Tags: perl, shell, terminal

I need to source configuration file `'eg.conf'` to terminal though perl script. I am using system command but its not working.
`system('. /etc/eg.conf'`)

Basically I am writing script in which later point it will use the environment variable (under conf file) for execute other process.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to make the config available from within Perl AND your config file is valid Perl code you can use `do` or `require` (see perldoc for more information).

What you are doing in your code is to spawn a shell with `system`, include the config inside this shell (which must be in shell syntax) and then exit the shell again which of course throws all the config away on close. I guess this is not what you intend to do, but your real intention is not clear.

Comment: Basically I am writing script in which later point it will use the environment variable (under conf file) for execute other process.

Comment: Then you source either these environment variables before calling the script within the callers shell, or source the variables before calling each sub-process within the sub-process shell or provide the variables not with shell syntax but with Perl syntax and read them with do/require. Don't expect that you can just include a shell program (what your config is) within Perl - these are both different programming languages. If your config has a specific config you can open and parse it from within Perl of course, but not shell code in general.

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal?  Do you need to source eg.conf to set up further calculations from within a perl controlled shell, or are you trying to affect the parent shell that is running the perl script?

Your example call to `system('. /etc/eg.conf')` creates a new shell subprocess.  /etc/eg.conf is sourced into that shell at which point the shell exits.  Nothing is changed within the perl script nor in the parent process that spawned the perl script.

One can not modify the environment of a parent process from a child process, without the assistance of the parent process[1].  One generally returns code for the parent shell to source or to eval.

1: ok, one could theoretically affect the parent process by directly poking into its memory space.  Don't do that.